# RestSharp - when a test runs for the first time, it fails. When I debug, it passes. what's going on?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, restsharp

Pretty basic test:

```
[TestClass]
public class ApiClientTest
{
    private RestClient _client;

    [TestInitialize()]
    public virtual void TestInitialize()
    {
        _client = new RestClient("http://localhost:24144");
        _client.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ApiClientTestCRUD()
        {
        // 1. Log out twice.  Verify Unauthorized.
        var response = LogOut();
        response = LogOut();
        Assert.AreEqual(response.StatusCode, HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        // Error here:
```

> Result Message:   Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<0>.
>   Actual:< Unauthorized >.

I get <0>, which isn't even something that my WebAPI returns.

I think the issue is with my use of RestSharp, because if I debug one time it passes, and then subsequent runs pass.  Any clue what's going on?

To be clear - this occurs when I open up my solution and attempt to run the test for the first time.  I can fix it by debugging once, watching it pass, and then running without debugging as much as I want.  I can reproduce this by closing VS and opening up the solution again - and running the test without debugging first.

Here's the LogOut method in my WebAPI:

```
    [Authorize]
    public HttpResponseMessage LogOut()
    {
        try
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                WebSecurity.Logout();
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "logged out successfully.");
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, "already done.");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
        }

    }
```

**UPDATE:**

I ended up running the tests with Trace.WriteLine:

```
        // 1. Log out twice.  Verify Unauthorized.
        Trace.WriteLine("ENTERING FIRST LOGOUT");
        var response = LogOut();
        Trace.WriteLine("Content: " + response.Content);
        Trace.WriteLine("ErrorMessage: " + response.ErrorMessage);
        Trace.WriteLine("ResponseStatus: " + response.ResponseStatus);
        Trace.WriteLine("StatusCode: " + response.StatusCode);
        Trace.WriteLine("StatusDescription: " + response.StatusDescription);
        response = LogOut();
        Trace.WriteLine("COMPLETED LOGOUTS");
        Assert.AreEqual(response.StatusCode, HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
```

And I found the following:

```
ENTERING FIRST LOGOUT
Content: 
ErrorMessage: Unable to connect to the remote server
ResponseStatus: Error
StatusCode: 0
StatusDescription: 
COMPLETED LOGOUTS
```

My solution has a test project with this RestSharp test, and a WebAPI project that's supposed to be accepting these requests.  If I debug, the RestClient connects.  If not, it times out.  Any tips?

Comment: User.Identity is got from Thread.CurrentPrincipal, which is static. If it is modified in one test, affects the rest of the tests. That might be the issue here. When you run multiple tests, you might have one or more tests modifying that static variable.

Comment: No other tests are being run... just this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When debugging is not possible to solve the problem go to the old fashion way.

Add Trace.WriteLine (or even append text to a C:\temp.txt file).

Write some string before every return in the LogOut method, then try writing some more information (if it's the last return then write the Exception message, if it's the second return write the Identity information.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that does help.  I updated my question with the results, any chance you can take a look?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see enough information to give you a proper solution.

Why is the trace output only 3 lines? Can you number each Trace.WriteLine("1" + first), Trace.WriteLine("2" + second) and so on so we can see where the message comes from?

Where is http://localhost:24144? is it from the same solution? Is it  created when first running the tests? Can you debug it seperately?

Comment: Updated with more details.  Localhost is from the same solution - it's the WebAPI project.  I can't debug it separately...  I posted up another question in case you'd like to answer there:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629388/tests-connecting-to-webapi-project-when-i-debug-but-not-when-i-run

Comment: Are you sure you can't seperate your test from the WebAPI? I can geuss that when running in debug, the target loads while visual studio is loading your symbols and when running without debug it doesn't manage to load in time, maybe you can somehow change the timeout of the RestClient (or of the WebAPI endpoint).
Found a similar problem here: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110117051325AA6nh2Q

Comment: I'll move my WebAPI tests into my client solution (consumes the WebAPI) and post back.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

How are you hosting the server? I see this that you're using port 24144. Maybe in debug mode you're running the express IIS Web Server and that's the port, but in non-debug mode it's not?